# Remove 0g value from when pulling data from a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Looking for help on writing a formula to pull all data from a column AC (picture 1), removing 0g values and move that data into a new column with no spaces which would look like picture 2.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please edit your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(AC3:AC, len(AC3:AC), left(AC3:AC, 2) <> "0g")`

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)